# Strange ubuntu bash issue

Tags: mysql, database, linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm working on bash script which looks like that. The idea is: to create script which will create mysql user, database and grant all priviligies to this user for newly created db.

```
    SED=`which sed`
CURRENT_DIR=`dirname $0`

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "No domain name given"
    exit 1
fi
DOMAIN=$1

# check the domain is valid!
PATTERN="^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$";
if [[ "$DOMAIN" =~ $PATTERN ]]; then
    DOMAIN=`echo $DOMAIN | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
    echo "Creating hosting for:" $DOMAIN
else
    echo "invalid domain name"
    exit 1 
fi

   echo "Do you want to create MySQL DB for Website (Y/n)?"
read CREATEDB

if [[ ( $CREATEDB == "y" ) || ( -z "$CREATEDB" ) ]]; then
    echo "Enter MySQL root login (leave blank for default value - root):"
    read MYSQLLOGIN 
    if [ -z "$MYSQLLOGIN" ]; then
        MYSQLLOGIN="root"
    fi
    echo "Enter MySQL root PASS:"
    read MYSQLROOTPASS
    if [ -z "$MYSQLROOTPASS" ]; then
        echo "No way without pass"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "Enter DB name (leave blank for default value - username_db):" 
    read MYSQLDB
    if [ -z "$MYSQLDB" ]; then
        MYSQLDB=$USERNAME"_db"
    fi
    echo "Enter password for newly created MySQL user (!ONLY if you have pwgen - sudo apt-get install pwgen! leave blank for auto password creation):"
    read MYSQLPASS
    if [ -z "$MYSQLPASS" ]; then
        MYSQLPASS=$(pwgen -acn 10 1)
    fi
    mysql -h localhost -u $MYSQLLOGIN -p$MYSQLROOTPASS;
    mysql> CREATE USER $USERNAME@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY $MYSQLPASS;
    mysql> create database $MYSQLDB;
    mysql> grant usage on *.* to $USERNAME@localhost identified by $MYSQLPASS;
    mysql> grant all privileges on $MYSQLDB.* to $USERNAME@localhost ;
else
exit 1
fi

echo -e "\nSite Created for $DOMAIN with PHP support\n Domain: "$DOMAIN"\n MySQL DB Name: "$MYSQLDB"\nMySQL Username : Pass"$USERNAME" : "$MYSQLPASS ;
```

What am I doing wrong? getting following error:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The error is in the line being highlighted:

```
    if[$MYSQLDB==""]; then
```

You need to have spaces around `[`, `]` and the `==` operator, say:

```
    if [ $MYSQLDB == "" ]; then
```

The same problem exists at other places, too.  For example, you're saying:

```
if [$CREATEDB == "y"]; then
if[$MYSQLLOGIN==""]; then
if[$MYSQLPASS==""]; then
```

Moreover, the following would not work:

```
mysql -h localhost -u $MYSQLLOGIN -p$MYSQLROOTPASS;
mysql> CREATE USER $USERNAME@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY $MYSQLPASS;
mysql> create database $MYSQLDB;
mysql> grant usage on *.* to $USERNAME@localhost identified by $MYSQLPASS;
mysql> grant all privileges on $MYSQLDB.* to $USERNAME@localhost ;
```

You need to use a [heredoc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents).

Comment: can you please make your modifications on code? I did what you say, still getting same error

Comment: @heron It seems that you need a `fi` statement for those `if`s.

Comment: @devnull: quite honestly, there is a *lot* missing or broken in this script. +1 for your patience...

Comment: Okay, fixed all bugs. But MySQL Commands doesn't execute. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @heron Use a heredoc as mentioned in the post above.

Comment: `mysql -h localhost -u $MYSQLLOGIN -p$MYSQLROOTPASS  < echo 
 "CREATE USER $USERNAME@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY $MYSQLPASS;
 create database $MYSQLDB;
 grant usage on *.* to $USERNAME@localhost identified by $MYSQLPASS;
 grant all privileges on $MYSQLDB.* to $USERNAME@localhost";` Did this, doesn't work. No errors outputed

Comment: @heron This isn't a **heredoc**.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
if[$MYSQLLOGIN==""]; then
```

has *at least* the following syntax errors:

- It needs a space between `if` and `[` - `if[` is not valid bash syntax
- It needs a space *after* the `[` - `[==` (when `MYSQLLOGIN` is empty) is not a valid command
- It needs a space before `]`
- I would argue that it also needs double quotes around your variable, to prevent issues with the input text: `"$MYSQLLOGIN"`

So the correct version would be:

```
if [ "$MYSQLLOGIN" == "" ]; then
```

The same mistakes are also repeated in other parts of your code, so you will have to fix those too.

Comment: still same error. can you please make your modifications on code?

Comment: Okay, fixed all bugs. But MySQL Commands doesn't execute. What am I doing wrong?  mysql -h localhost -u $MYSQLLOGIN -p$MYSQLROOTPASS  < echo 
 "CREATE USER $USERNAME@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY $MYSQLPASS;
 create database $MYSQLDB;
 grant usage on *.* to $USERNAME@localhost identified by $MYSQLPASS;
 grant all privileges on $MYSQLDB.* to $USERNAME@localhost";